# Iterate through deeply nested object to generate html optgroup/options

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, nested, javascript-objects

I am trying to get the keys of my object and create an optgroup if it contains children and then make children options of the optgroup. If a child is also a object than i want to nest another optgroup within parent optgroup. Below is my object myTypes

```
let myTypes = {
    women: 
    {
        tops:
        {
            poloshirts:"polo shirts",
            tshirts: "t-shirts",
            buttondown: "button down",
            longsleeve:"long sleeve",
            vneck:"vneck",
            tanktop:"tanktop",
            blouse:"blouse",
            croptop:"croptop",
            drifit: "dri-fit",
            dressshirt:"dress shirt"
        },
        bottoms:
        {
            shorts:"shorts",
            jeans:"jeans",
            joggers:"joggers",
            skirts:"skirts",
            dresspants:"dresspants",
            leggings:"leggings"
        },
        shoes:
        {
            boots:"boots",
            sneakers: "sneakers",
            sandals:"sandals",
            flats:"flats",
            heels:"heels"
        },
        jewelry:
        {
            rings: "rings",
            bracelets:"bracelets",
            necklaces: "necklaces",
            anklets: "anklets"
        },
        sweaters: "sweaters",
        sweatshirts: "sweatshirts",
        hoodies: "hoodies",
        dresses:
        {
            sundress: "sundress",
            short: "short",
            long: "long",
            maxidress: "maxidress"
        },
        accessories:
        {
            watches:"watches",
            glasses:
            {
                sunglasses: "sunglasses",
                reading:"reading"
            },
            wallets: "wallets",
            keychains: "keychains",
            lanyards:"lanyards",
            belts:"belts",
            purses:"purses"
        }
    },
    
men: 
    {
        tops:
        {
            poloshirts:"polo shirts",
            tshirts: "t-shirts",
            buttondown: "button down",
            longsleeve:"long sleeve",
            vneck:"vneck",
            tanktop:"tanktop",
            drifit: "dri-fit",
            dressshirt: "dress shirt"
        },
        bottoms:
        {
            shorts:"shorts",
            jeans:"jeans",
            joggers:"joggers",
            dresspants:"dress pants",
            leggings:"leggings"
        },
        shoes:
        {
            boots:"boots",
            sneakers: "sneakers",
            sandals:"sandals",
            flats:"flats"
        },
        jewelry:
        {
            rings: "rings",
            bracelets:"bracelets",
            necklaces: "necklaces",
            anklets: "anklets"
        },
        sweaters: "sweaters",
        sweatshirts: "sweatshirts",
        hoodies: "hoodies",
        accessories:
        {
            watches:"watches",
            glasses:
            {
                sunglasses: "sunglasses",
                reading:"reading"
            },
            wallets: "wallets",
            keychains: "keychains",
            lanyards:"lanyards",
            belts:"belts"
        }
    },
kids: 
    {
    girl: 
        {
            tops:
            {
                poloshirts:"polo shirts",
                tshirts: "t-shirts",
                buttondown: "button down",
                longsleeve:"long sleeve",
                vneck:"vneck",
                tanktop:"tanktop",
                blouse:"blouse",
                croptop:"croptop",
                drifit: "dri-fit",
                dressshirt:"dress shirt"
            },
            bottoms:
            {
                shorts:"shorts",
                jeans:"jeans",
                joggers:"joggers",
                skirts:"skirts",
                dresspants:"dresspants",
                leggings:"leggings"
            },
            shoes:
            {
                boots:"boots",
                sneakers: "sneakers",
                sandals:"sandals",
                flats:"flats",
                heels:"heels"
            },
            jewelry:
            {
                rings: "rings",
                bracelets:"bracelets",
                necklaces: "necklaces",
                anklets: "anklets"
            },
            sweaters: "sweaters",
            sweatshirts: "sweatshirts",
            hoodies: "hoodies",
            dresses:
            {
                sundress: "sundress",
                short: "short",
                long: "long",
                maxidress: "maxidress"
            },
            accessories:
            {
                watches:"watches",
                glasses:
                {
                    sunglasses: "sunglasses",
                    reading:"reading"
                },
                wallets: "wallets",
                keychains: "keychains",
                lanyards:"lanyards",
                belts:"belts",
                purses:"purses"
            }
        },
    boy: 
        {
            tops:
            {
                poloshirts:"polo shirts",
                tshirts: "t-shirts",
                buttondown: "button down",
                longsleeve:"long sleeve",
                vneck:"vneck",
                tanktop:"tanktop",
                drifit: "dri-fit",
                dressshirt: "dress shirt"
            },
            bottoms:
            {
                shorts:"shorts",
                jeans:"jeans",
                joggers:"joggers",
                dresspants:"dress pants",
                leggings:"leggings"
            },
            shoes:
            {
                boots:"boots",
                sneakers: "sneakers",
                sandals:"sandals",
                flats:"flats"
            },
            jewelry:
            {
                rings: "rings",
                bracelets:"bracelets",
                necklaces: "necklaces",
                anklets: "anklets"
            },
            sweaters: "sweaters",
            sweatshirts: "sweatshirts",
            hoodies: "hoodies",
            accessories:
            {
                watches:"watches",
                glasses:
                {
                    sunglasses: "sunglasses",
                    reading:"reading"
                },
                wallets: "wallets",
                keychains: "keychains",
                lanyards:"lanyards",
                belts:"belts"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to iterate through this and then generate html selection with the appropiate options, but I cannot figure it out. The furthest I've gotten is this

```
    let selectionHTML = "";
    let paths = (arr)=>{
        for(let i in arr){
            if(typeof arr[i] == "object" && arr[i] !== null){
                selectionHTML += "<optgroup label = '" + i + "'></optgroup>";
                paths(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    paths(myTypes);
```

I've no clue how to go about generating my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know that using the approach of nesting `optgroup` elements together does not work, as only the first level of `optgroup` will be displayed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Try using something like that:

```js
const path = (source = {}) => {
  // Let the initial string be empty
  let returnedString = '';

  // Convert the object into an array using key/value pair and then iterate through it
  Object.entries(source)
    .forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        // value is an object, iterate through it
        returnedString += `<optgroup label="${key}">${path(value)}</optgroup>`;
      } else {
        // value should be a string
        returnedString += `<option value="${key}">${value}</option>`;
      }
    });

  // Return the string
  return returnedString;
}
```

also, while manipulating the DOM, it is recommended to used built-in methods for manipulating elements instead of strings:

```js
// Create the "root" element
// const root = document.createElement('select');

const path = (source = {}, rootElement = undefined) => {
  // Define the root element if not an instance of Element
  const root= rootElement instanceof Element ? rootElement : document.createElement('select');

  // Convert the object into an array using key/value pair and then iterate through it
  Object.entries(source)
    .forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) { // value is an object, iterate through it
        // Create an optgroup element
        const optgroup = document.createElement('optgroup');

        // Defines the attributes
        optgroup.setAttribute('label', key);

        // Add "content" inside the optgroup
        path(value, optgroup);

        // Append the newly created optgroup element to the root
        root.appendChild(optgroup);
      } else { // value should be a string
        // Create an option element
        const option = document.createElement('option');

        // Defines the attributes
        option.setAttribute('value', key);
        option.text = value;

        // Append the newly created option element to the root
        root.appendChild(option);
      }
    });

  // Return the root element
  return root;
}
```

EDIT 1: Added DOM way to the answer

EDIT 2: Added warning of `optgroup` nesting

Answer (score 0):

```html
function getMyTypes(obj_myTypes) {

    var targetHTML = $("");
    
    for (const key in obj_myTypes) {
        if (obj_myTypes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var element = obj_myTypes[key];
            console.log(key)
            targetHTML.prepend(`<optgroup id="one" label="${key}"> ${key} </optgroup>`);
            //each in obj
            //console.log(element)
            stepTwo(element)
        }
    }
}
getMyTypes(myTypes);

function stepOne() {
    var step_one = $('optgroup').filter('[id="one"]');
        step_one.each((index) => {
           // var result = $(this).text()
            step_one.prepend(`<optgroup id="two" label=""> two </optgroup>`)
        });
}
stepOne()

function stepTwo(obj_elem) {

    var step_two = $('optgroup').filter('[id="two"]');
    
    for (const key in obj_elem) {
        if (obj_elem.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var item_of_element = obj_elem[key];
            console.log('KEY: '+key)

            step_two.each((index,html_element) => {
                $(html_element).attr("label", value)
                console.log(value)
                //return value
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that you must go through the object three times. In the response of each loop, you must add it to the html.